# Static new and inheritance

Tags: axapta, x++

[Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa594035%28v=ax.10%29) recommend setting the new method as protected and using instead static new... methods to mitigate the lack of method overloading.
So I use this pattern as explained [here](http://www.artofcreation.be/2010/05/18/creating-a-class-the-best-practice-way/)

But static methods are not inherited.
So we have to define for each sub class the static construct and the static new... methods.
Therefore we lose some of inheritance's benefits.

I had a look on system classes hoping to find a better solution but what I saw did not really help me :
- some respect the static new pattern and declare the methods in the sub classes
- some just use the instance new without protecting it
- some use the mother class as a "class factory", like SalesFormLetter

```
static SalesFormLetter  construct(DocumentStatus    document,
                                  boolean           getParmId = true)
    {
    switch(document)
    {
        case DocumentStatus::Confirmation       :   return new SalesFormLetter_Confirm           (getParmId);
        case DocumentStatus::PickingList        :   return SalesFormLetter_PickingList::construct(getParmId);
        case DocumentStatus::PackingSlip        :   return new SalesFormLetter_PackingSlip       (getParmId);
        case DocumentStatus::ProjectPackingSlip :   return new SalesFormLetter_PackingSlipProject(getParmId);
        case DocumentStatus::Invoice            :   return new SalesFormLetter_Invoice           (getParmId);
        case DocumentStatus::ProjectInvoice     :   return new SalesFormLetter_InvoiceProject    (getParmId);

        default : throw error(strfmt("@SYS19306",funcname()));
    }

    throw error(strfmt("@SYS19306",funcname()));
}
```

So I am wondering if there is a better solution, and if not what would be the best among these ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution to object construction?

Well, the `new` have to go somewhere, and putting a lot of `new` in the client code is fragile and inflexible. So go with the class "factories" especially for related classes.

Two options:

1. Make `new` protected. Make a construct for each sub-class, put the factory construct in the base class calling the sub-class constructors. But anyone can then call the sub-class construct method.
2. Make `new` public. Don't make a construct for each sub-class, put factory the construct in the base class, new'ing the sub-classes. The new can't be protected as the base class does not descend from the sub-class.

Whether or not you go with 1 or 2 is your choice, you end up with exposing the sub-class constructor. Personally I prefer option 2, as it is the least hassle.

Advice: make your object dependencies explicit using arguments to `new`. This will complicate your factories, but that is okay as it moves the complexity from your client code. Setter methods (`parm` methods) is evil, but is needed for `RunBase` because the it is required by the batch system.

Also go see what [Uncle Bob](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/17/dependency-injection-inversion) writes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
I think I am going to need some time to fully understand it and to put it into practice.